# DiscoveryClient_xxx:111-222:8080 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server

Tags: netflix-eureka

DiscoveryClient_xxx:111-222:8080 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server :

I run a spring cloud application on my localhost.and i register with localhost eureka.but i got the following output:

```
Request execution error
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at 

017-07-01 13:13:41 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] (DiscoveryClient.java:937)  - Disable delta property : false
2017-07-01 13:13:41 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] (DiscoveryClient.java:938)  - Single vip registry refresh property : null
2017-07-01 13:13:41 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] (DiscoveryClient.java:939)  - Force full registry fetch : false
2017-07-01 13:13:41 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] (DiscoveryClient.java:940)  - Application is null : false
2017-07-01 13:13:41 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] (DiscoveryClient.java:941)  - Registered Applications size is zero : true
2017-07-01 13:13:41 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] (DiscoveryClient.java:943)  - Application version is -1: true
2017-07-01 13:13:41 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] (DiscoveryClient.java:1026)  - Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2017-07-01 13:13:41 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] (RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:83)  - Request execution error
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at         com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at     com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:194) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:165) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1030) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:944) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1468) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1435) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
... 30 more
2017-07-01 13:13:41 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] (RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:129)  - Request execution failure
2017-07-01 13:13:41 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] (DiscoveryClient.java:951)  - DiscoveryClient_JGJ-SFB/10.2.238.227:jgj-sfb:9875 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1030) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:944) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1468) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1435) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_92]
2017-07-01 13:13:41 [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] (DiscoveryClient.java:812)  - DiscoveryClient_JGJ-SFB/10.2.238.227:jgj-sfb:9875: registering service...
2017-07-01 13:13:41 [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] (RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:83)  - Request execution error
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at     com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
```

what's the problem?

Comment: Can you share the code for the client and its configuration?

Comment: sorry。It turns out that ,I didn't config the eureka host and port :eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${EUREKA_1_SERVICE_HOST}:${EUREKA_1_SERVICE_PORT}/eureka/,http://${EUREKA_2_SERVICE_HOST}:${EUREKA_2_SERVICE_PORT}/eureka/  it leads me to another problem . using config server,if you have application.yaml and appliation-test.yaml and set the profle to test.  configserver will combine the two file?

Answer (score 12):

Adding the below properties to `application.properties` fixed the issue for me, you can give it a try.

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Comment: Did it registered your microservice with eureka ?

Answer (score 1):

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

and ensure half angle characters